# Send Enum value in another script?

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine, sendmessage

I would like to pass an enum value in a function of another script (in C#, and Unity3d), if I directly pass them through public variables, I have got an "Inconsistent accessibility" error (field type 'xx' is less accessible than field 'xx'), and I did not find how to solve this. (attempt#1 below)

So I have tried to pass a List through the SendMessage function (that can only send 1 object), but it now says

> *"error CS0246: The type or namespace name `List`1' could not be found.
>   Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"*

Would you know how to do this?

Here are my attempts :

```
private AState currentAState;//attempt #1 //with all my var "public" : same thing
//...
modelGOscript.currentA = currentAState;//#1
//...
modelGO.SendMessage ("animToPlay", new List<AState>(currentAState, newAState) );//#2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inconsistent accessibility typically refers to the class level(s) involved.

Make sure the classes, enums, etc. you are using line up properly with regards to accessibility.

```
public class XScript
public enum AState
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, I thought I changed the enum to be public, but maybe I made a mistake, it works fine now, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `AState` is defined as `private` and `modelGOscript`'s property probably defined as `public`, `protected` or `internal`. Try to give `AState` less restrictive [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Denys, no even with all of them being "public", it triggers the same error...

Comment: Is `AState` enum is public itself? I mean `public enum AState { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, yep I think I did it at first, and with all the errors I changed it back to "enum". Thanks a lot for your help!